# Time complexity for a loop with two nested loops?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

I understand that

```
var arr;  // This is an array of arrays 

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{

  for(j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
  {
   // Some code
  }
}
```

is n^2, however my code below is a double nested for loop and im just curious on what the complexity for this type of function would look like

```
var arr;  // This is an array of arrays


for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{

  for(j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
  {
   // Some code
  }

  for(k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++)
  {
   // Some code
  }
}
```

Comment: It's the same. You've just multiplied by a constant factor, and that has no effect on complexity.

Comment: The complexity is still the same, but, your analogy of n^2 stand if all the columns are of the same length as rows else the complexity is rows * columns

Comment: If you search on the phrase "How to compute algorithm time complexity", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity of consecutive pieces of code is the maximum complexity of each of them. So if you have two consecutive loops, and they're both `O(n)`, then the complexity of both together is also `O(n)`.

Since these two loops are nested inside an `O(n)` loop, the complexity of the whole thing is `O(n^2)`. Just like the complexity of the original code.

Answer (score 2):

A loop has the complexity `O(n * content)`, a block of statement has the complexity of all its members added up `O(n1 + n2 + ...)`. Now in your case that is

```
// v outer loop
//      v inner loop 1
//                v inner loop 2
O(n * ((n * 1) + (n * 1)))
= O(n * (n + n))
= O(n * 2n) // constants can be ignored
= O(n * n)
= O(n²)
```